# Using microcomputer pin alternate functions

Tags: microcontroller

I hope this isn't too general a question, but how does one use an alternate pin function when programming a microcomputer.  Specifically, does one have to "tell" the microcomputer that you're using the pin for a function other than its default.  I realize that it's done, in effect, when one sets up SPI or I2C, for example, but is it language specific, so that in C/C++ one has to specifically identify the function one is going to use in some fashion.  So, for GPIO (or whatever the default function is) one doesn't have to do anything, but if one wants to use a pin's alternate function 3 (let's say it's U2-RXD one has to communicate that explicitly to the microcontroller? Pardon the "stupid" question.

Comment: Depends *a lot* on the microcontroller, but you usually set a value inside a registry.

Comment: Yes you have to tell the device which function you want to use for those pins.  Depending on the device and the pin you might only have to configure the alternate function, but there may be times you have to mess with the gpio for example i2c might require you use the gpio pull up but the i2c alternate function.  And sometimes you dont.  Unfortunately outside which alternate function is which details like this are often not documented and you have to figure it out.

Comment: not all pins on all mcus default to gpio, some default to jtag or other debug/programming interface, some default to uart, etc.   dont assume gpio is always the default despite it being that way 99.999% of the time.

Comment: Thanks.  It seems as though the answer is "it depends" and that would be the question as to whether the datasheet for the mcu would be the place to go to get the definitive answer for a particular MCU?

Answer (score 0):

I'll take "it depends" as the definitive answer and defer to the datasheet for follow-up.
Thanks.